# How to convert Date and time into unix timestamp in google sheet

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, unix-timestamp

I have a google sheet where I have one column contains Date and time in the following format

```
15-08-2021 12:30:00
```

I want to convert whole column into unix timestamp including hours , minutes and seconds . above date and time should give following result

```
1629012600
```

I tried to find solution but there are clear solutions of converting unix timestamp into human readable format or conversion of Date and time into unix timestamp in other languages like php, python , js etc. but I didn't find any solution for google sheet.

how to convert Date and time into unix timestamp in google sheet.

Comment: "_there are clear solutions... in other languages like... js_" - The scripting language for Google Sheets is JavaScript. See the introduction [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview).

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I was trying to find out how to do this in a cell, not use Google Apps Script.

Answer (score 1):

(new Date(2021,7,15,12,30,0).valueOf()/1000).toFixed();

Comment: In a cell, you could just use

    =((NOW()-DATE(1970,1,1)+time(6,0,0))*86400)